# Different value in While loop

Tags: php, mysql, while-loop

i want to get only 4 values from while loop in different variables.For example i want like this

```
$Var1 = "value1";
$Var2 = "value2";
$Var3 = "value3";
$Var4 = "value4";
```

here is my while loop

```
while($rw = $oAppl->row($rsimg))
        {
             //get value here
             $var1 = $rw['thumb'];
        }
```

But no value can be repeatable,i only have thumb returned.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you cannot store more than one value inside a variable, you can either echo while `looping`

```
while($rw = $oAppl->row($rsimg))
{
     //get value here
     echo $rw['thumb'] . '<br>';
}
```

or create a new array to use all values later

```
$thumbs = array();
while($rw = $oAppl->row($rsimg))
{
     //get value here
     $thumbs[] = $rw['thumb'];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to set var1, 2, 3, 4 then stop, you need to keep track how many iterations the loop has gone through. (Alternatively a for loop may perform this task better)

```
$i = 1;
while ($rw = $oAppl->row($rsimg)) {
    if ($i > 4) break;
    eval("$Var" . $i . " = '" . $rw['thumb'] . "';");
    $i++;
}
```

If storing values in $varNUM is not a requirement, I would suggest using an array to store these variables instead of using separate variables.